# Subgroups of $G$ if there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $C_2$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Is there always a subgroup of index 2 in $G$ if there is a homomorphism $f: G \rightarrow C_2$? My inkling is that this is true because in this case $G$ must have a normal subgroup of index 2, and the result follows from Lagrange's theorem. Could someone please help me and provide a solution?

Comment: By the Isomorphism Theorems, $f(G)\cong G/\mathrm{ker}(f)$. Thus, there is a normal subgroup $N=\mathrm{ker}(f)\triangleleft G$ such that $[G:N]=2$. Therefore, $|G|=|N|[G:N]=2|N|$, so $|G|$ is even.

Comment: @ArturoMagidinn If the map were onto, yes, but...

Comment: @IgorRivin: When I wrote the comment, surjectivity was an assumption. You can see that [in the revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4064977/revisions). My comment was posted on 2021-03-17 03:59:43Z, the edit deleting the assumption of surjectivity was made on 2021-03-17 04:44:00Z, almost 45 minutes later.

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on the other answer and comments:

Given any two groups $G$ and $H$, there is always a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$, namely the trivial map which sends every element of $G$ to the identity in $H$.

What you want is the following:

**Theorem.**

$G$ has a subgroup of index $2$ if and only if there is a *non-trivial* homomorphism $G \to C_2$.

**Proof.**

Note first that because $C_2$ has only $2$ elements, a homomorphism $G \to C_2$ is surjective if and only if it is non-trivial. Now:

- ($\Rightarrow$). If $G$ has a subgroup $N$ of index $2$, this subgroup is automatically normal and therefore $G / N$ is a group which has order $2$ and hence is isomorphic to $C_2$. Therefore the projection map $G \to G/N$ gives a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $C_2$ which as mentioned above, must be non-trivial.
- ($\Leftarrow$). If there exists a non-trivial homomorphism $\varphi: G \to C_2$, as mentioned above, $\varphi$ must be surjective. Hence by Lagrange, the kernel of $\varphi$ has index $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Need not have a subgroup of index 2.

For counter-example: It is well known that $A_5$ does not have a subgroup of index 2.
But, there is a trivial homomorphism from $A_5$ to $C_2$.
Even if it is not onto, which is not mandatory in the question.